# Finding affine transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry, quadratic-forms, affine-geometry

Find affine transformation which takes the ellipse $x^2+4y^2+2x-8y+3=0$ to the form of the ellipse ${x^2 \over 9}+{y^2 \over 16}=1$.

So I took the quadric and reached to a standard form: ${(x+1)^2 \over 2}+{(y-1)^2 \over {1 \over 2}}=1$.

So the constant vector in the affine transformation is $(-1,1)$. But how do I find the matrix needed? [Affine transformation as I know it is $T_A(\vec v)=A \vec v+\vec a$, so I found $\vec a=(-1,1)$].

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT : 
$$\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}+\frac{(y-1)^2}{\frac 12}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{\frac 12}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{3}x\right)^2}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}y\right)^2}{\frac 12}=1$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$$

Comment: Yes. So first you 'moved' the ellipse back to (0,0), and than you made it smaller? So the matrix A is = $\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt2 \over 3 & 0\\ 0& 1\over 4 \sqrt2 \end{bmatrix}$? And the transformation is $T=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt2 \over 3 & 0\\ 0& 1\over 4 \sqrt2 \end{bmatrix} \vec v+(1,-1)$?

Comment: Note that the last is $(1,-1)$ instead of $(-1,1)$ because the center of the first ellipse is $(-1,1).$

Comment: Ah, right. My bad. Thanks! And the following question is whether exists an isometry doing the same action. How can I check that?

Comment: By isometric transformation, I mean that the matrix A is orthogonal.

Comment: Do you know the definition of isometry?

Comment: I don't have a textbook :[ Can you recommend on a good source for this subject?

Comment: OK. I recommend you to read the following page carefully. Good luck! and Enjoy studying math! and A Happy New Year!:)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry